# Accordion not working within a tab in IE9 (works fine everywhere else)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, tabs, accordion

I'm using jquery vertical tabs and a jquery accordion within the second tab. It works GREAT (Mac) in Firefox 17.0.1, Chrome 23.0.1271.95, Safari 5.1.7, SeaMonkey 2.0.11, my iPhone4, my wife's Android - but the accordion will not function in IE 9. (haven't tried any other version of IE)

Can someone help me track down the problem?

http://www.geneseo.com/yes

The tabs should default to the second tab which contains the accordion.

I appreciate any help in this.

Thanks - Ron

Update: In addition, in IE9 the links on the final tab (ColoHub) do not work, yet they work in other browers?

Comment: Just tested in ie8. Its working fine for me including the links on the last tab. What error are you seeing?

Comment: http://s1327.beta.photobucket.com/user/fresheyeball/media/ScreenShot2012-12-13at92027AM.png.html

Comment: My bad - helps to know what browser I'm using! WhenI first load IE, it is version 9. Which is where I see the problem, though no errors.  When I make changes in the f12 developer settings - it starts to work. But on first load IE, no go. Simply, anything clickable is not clickable.

Comment: working fine for me in ie9 as well

Answer (score 0):

I believe you must have a stray `console.log` in your application somewhere. Unlike good browsers, IE only provides a console object if developer tools are open. So using `console.log` with developer tools open can cause your javascript to crash and burn. Here is a handy snippet to stop IE from being a jerk with its handeling of the console.

```
 if(!window.console){
     window.console = { log : $.noop }
 }
```

This way if the console object is not found, `console.log` becomes noop instead of null and does not crash IE.

Comment: Hello again - I had my IT folks try it.  It works for them. He had me reset my IE settings (Internet Options, Advanced, Reset) - and it worked on my browser.  Strange indeed. Thanks to each of you for your input and assistance!